# How to setup up LSP for C/C++ in Vim?

Tags: lsp, filetype-c++

I would like:

- auto complete,
- navigation,
- refactoring

using LSP in Vim not in Neovim.

I would like some guide and example to setup `.vimrc`

Can I find one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular choice is [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) together with [clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/).

You need first to install:

- [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- [clangd](https://clangd.llvm.org/)

There are many ways to install [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) like for any plugin in Vim. A popular choice is to install the [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager and to have the following lines in your `.vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim'
call plug#end()
```

Restart Vim and run the following commands:

```
:PlugInstall
:CocInstall coc-clangd
```

You can follow the coc.nvim [instructions](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim#example-vim-configuration) to adapt your `.vimrc`

```
" ...
" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate
" NOTE: There's always complete item selected by default, you may want to enable
" no select by `"suggest.noselect": true` in your configuration file
" NOTE: Use command ':verbose imap <tab>' to make sure tab is not mapped by
" other plugin before putting this into your config
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) :
      \ CheckBackspace() ? "\<Tab>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(1) : "\<C-h>"

" Make <CR> to accept selected completion item or notify coc.nvim to format
" <C-g>u breaks current undo, please make your own choice
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"

function! CheckBackspace() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction

" Use <c-space> to trigger completion
if has('nvim')
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
else
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-@> coc#refresh()
endif
" ...
" GoTo code navigation
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
" ...
" Symbol renaming
nmap <leader>rn <Plug>(coc-rename)
" ...
```

Restart Vim.

You should be good with completion and:

- `gd` to go to definition and
- `rn` for renaming

Comment: Thanks to Vivian De Smedt, I was able to make my vimrc work for LSP : https://github.com/jumogehn/vimrc

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm happy you managed to configure coc.nvim I'm using it everyday and it is very powerfull :-)